# How to make event marked as big colour circle in FSCalendar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fscalendar

I'm using FSCalendar in my app and I would like to add some events to my calendar by instead of small dots (the default way for marking event) I would like to mark the day with an event as big colour circle (the same way as e.g. the current day is marked in FSCalendar).

So basically my question is :
**How can I change background colour of any given day ?**

Below you can see I picture which I found on https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar
You can see many colours on the calendar so I assume it is possible to mark the day as I want but also I couldn't find right property or function to provide this output.

[image: big colour circle on calendar]

thanks for your time and help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following:

1. Add a delegate `FSCalendarDelegateAppearance`
2. Use method `fillDefaultColorFor`

   ```
   func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

    //format date according your need

    let calendarDateString = date.stringFromLocal(Format: "MM/dd/yyyy") 

    //your events date array

    if dateOfEvents.contains(calendarDateString) {

        return UIColor.blue

    }

    return nil //add your color for default 

   }
   ```

Comment: yup, that will do it, thank you. maybe a better idea would be returning nil as default because when I used UIColor.clear the current day on calendar was "invisible"